# How to disable unwanted ImageView in my application

Tags: android

I have 5 `ImageView` in my xml. Firebase is my backend. Some times I only need 2 images so I only insert 2 images in my firebase database. But the other 3 `ImageView` space still shows in my android application. How to disable unwanted ImageView in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 : Make the unwanted imageView visibility GONE.

```
imageView3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
imageView4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
imageVie5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

> OR

Medthod 2 : Create ImageView Dynamically using code. So no need of declaring imageView in xml

Comment: how to visible imageview3  when i insert images in imagesviews3

Comment: imageView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);